# Изменение стандартного цвета выделения кнопки при наведении

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавляю разноцветную кнопку, навожу мышку и тут бац это мерзкое синее выделение.

Может кто знает как исправить?

Использую Windows Forms.

Comment: .NET Насколько я знаю

Comment: емм... тогда без разницы?
(могу использовать оба)

Comment: Нет он практического значения програма вигледит уродливо, и я готов использовать что угодно для обеспечения качества

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67718/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на WPF, то вот небольшой стиль:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EvilUI">

    <Color x:Key="MouseLeave" A="255" R="69" G="69" B="69" />
    <Color x:Key="MouseOver" A="255" R="105" G="105" B="105" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="#EEE"/>


    <!--Button Style-->
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B7B7B7"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="TemplateBorder" 
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BtnBgColor" Color="{StaticResource MouseLeave}"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <!--<Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="TemplateBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.05" ScaleY="1.05"></ScaleTransform>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>-->
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="EnterMouse">
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BtnBgColor"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="{StaticResource MouseOver}"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0:0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="LeaveMouse">
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BtnBgColor"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                        To="{StaticResource MouseLeave}"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0:0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <!--<MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="TemplateBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"></ScaleTransform>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Ну на WinForms через свойство [`FlatAppearance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatappearance(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как то так

FlatStyle надо сделать равным Flat то есть будет плоская как в 10 винде.

Comment: Спасибо!
А на winforms никак?

Comment: Дополнил ответ у

Comment: @Санитариум, вы скрин такой специально выложили, чтоб мы вашу обоину заценили? 3/4 можно обрезать и сэкономить людям траффик заодно. Поставил минус за оформление, исправите - уберу

Comment: И ещё, чёрный обводящий овал на тёмно-сером фоне очень плохо различим. Обведите лучше красным. // cc: @Андрей

Comment: И да, мы уже поняли, что у вас крутая игровая видеокарта в SLI режиме и четыре монитора. Теперь обрежьте, пожалуйста, картинку.

Comment: ))) я бы не отказался от 4 мониторов и видяхи)